# Qt menu shortcuts preempt child widget KeyPressEvents

Tags: python, pyqt, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a main window in which I establish the standard Edit > Cut/Copy/Paste actions, with the menu actions linked to the relevant slots of a QTextEdit which is a child of the main window.

The main window has a different child (on the other side of a splitter) which displays a TableView. This widget has focus policy of click to focus and a KeyPressEvent handler. When this child has the focus, its KeyPressEvent method intercepts all keystroke events (I know because it prints them out on the console) EXCEPT ctl-c, ctl-v, and any other key sequences that are assigned to the edit or file menu actions. Those keystrokes go to the menu and take effect within the QTextEdit which does not have the focus.

I want to be able to catch ^c within the table view to copy the value of the table selection, but the key sequence never gets there.

What can I do to make the ^c action visible to the widget that has the focus?

Answer (score 1):

When the edit actions are created, give them a [WidgetShortcut](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt.html#ShortcutContext-enum) context and [add them](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#addAction) to the widget(s) they are to be associated with:

```
copyAction.setShortcutContext(Qt.WidgetShortcut)
editor.addAction(copyAction)
```

Note that the shortcuts of actions configured in this way won't override any of the built-in shortcuts the associated widgets may have.

**EDIT**

Here's a simple demo. Note that, when the *text-edit* has the keyboard focus, 'Ctrl+P' will trigger the handler, but 'Ctrl+C won't, because it is a built-in shortcut. When the *table* has the keyboard focus, 'Ctrl+C' will copy the selected item as normal, but 'Ctrl+P' will do nothing.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.edit = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.edit.setText('text')
        self.table = Table(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&File')
        def add_action(text, shortcut):
            action = menu.addAction(text)
            action.setShortcut(shortcut)
            action.triggered.connect(self.handleAction)
            action.setShortcutContext(QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut)
            self.edit.addAction(action)
        add_action('&Copy', 'Ctrl+C')
        add_action('&Print', 'Ctrl+P')

    def handleAction(self):
        print ('Action!')

class Table(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QTableWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setRowCount(4)
        self.setColumnCount(2)
        self.setItem(0, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('item'))

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print ('keyPressEvent: %s' % event.key())
        QtGui.QTableWidget.keyPressEvent(self, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't seem to work. I realized on reading this that all my menu actions were given parents of the main window, so I changed that so that specifically Edit>Cut/Copy/Paste actions are given the parent of the QTextEdit widget (itself a child of the main window). Also for those actions specifically I did the setShortcutContext as you suggest. However, cmd-C still goes to the edit menu and isn't intercepted by the other widget's keyPressEvent.

Comment: For a temporary workaround I am going to use cmd-shift-c in the table widget, it is seen by the keyPressEvent. But I sure hope to figure this out. Thanks again.

Comment: @user405. Works perfectly fine for me on Linux. I've added a simple demo to my answer for you to try. What platform are you on?

Comment: I've returned to this after a bit of a lapse. Thanks again for the demo, which in fact illustrates my problem nicely. It is never possible to intercept the ^C keyEvent (your keyPressEvent is never entered for ^C no matter where the focus is). Your table widget will execute Copy **provided** that one has double-clicked a cell bringing up the cell delegate editor, selected the text. However, what I want to do is to get control when a table cell or CELLS are merely hilited (single-click, ctl-click, shift-click) and copy all their texts as a string to the app clipboard. Can't do that.

Comment: @user405. I tested this on both Linux and WinXP, and it works perfectly fine for me. That is, if I select the text in the editor and do Ctrl+C, "text" is copied to the clipboard. And if I select (not edit) the top-left cell in the table and do Ctrl+C, "item" is copied to the clipboard. Also, all `keyPressEvents` (including Ctrl+C) are printed when the table has the focus. So the problem must be with your own code (which you haven't shown), rather than with my example.

Comment: Yup. The issue is PyQt in OSX. I just verified what you say in Linux and Win7 vm's. Running your code on OSX however, cmd-C (which Qt treats as ctl-c) in the table traps only ONE key event, 1000021 (Key_Control) and the clipboard is unchanged (not set to "item"). Also cmd-p in the table gets only the 1000021 followed by Menu Action. So that too is being preempted by the menu bar. This appears to be a Qt versus Mac OS compatibility issue then. Thanks again for your help.